# Should I print to the page from a javascript object, or only render from PHP?

Tags: object-oriented, php, javascript, optimization

I have a complex app on the Javascript/PHP/SQL stack which manages different domain objects. The Javascript layer contains classes which manage the data on the client side.

I am currently baking a bunch of data into the page render by PHP, in the `data-*` attributes, then reading it back into my javascript class hierarchy on page load. The problem here is that whenever I go to update any of my javascript data based on user interactions or pushes from the server, I have to maintain the `data-*` entries in the DOM as well.

It seems to me that the better idea would be to keep all the data in the javascript class hierarchy and print to the screen directly using the `createElement` functions, but as I understand it that soon becomes expensive due to DOM reflow.

So I'm tossing up between more complex data management with less server calls or clearer data structure with heavier overhead. Are there any nicer ways to manage printing to the screen from Javascript than `createElement, setAttribute, classList` etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the ways to Print on Screen by using Java Script would be with the **createDocumentFragment** function.

As explained in those docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment

This method is applicable if you need to append multiple DOM nodes in one place.
List items to a list for example (or just multiple divs to a parent div).
Basically you append all of the li to the Document Fragment and then append the fragment to the ul.

This way you will not have a reflow each time you add another li, but only once when the fragment is appended.

Another post on this subject: https://coderwall.com/p/o9ws2g/why-you-should-always-append-dom-elements-using-documentfragments